# поясните конструкцию - map (JavaScript/TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, map, rxjs

Не могу найти пояснение в гугле конструкции map:

```
phones = ["iPhone 7", "LG G 5", "Honor 9", "Idol S4", "Nexus 6P"];
phone: Observable<string>;

showPhones() {
       this.phone = Observable.interval(500).map(i=> this.phones[i]);
}
```

А именно интересует:

```
map(i=> this.phones[i]);
```

Очень похоже на метод foreach в map, но не совсем, что б не было неясностей решил уточнить у Вас что б больше не было сомнений. (На всякий случай уточню что фрагмент кода написан на TypeScript, но в ЖС точно такое встречал)

Comment: [Observable.interval](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/interval.md)

Comment: Путем перебора массива возвращает новый, но например немного измененный, либо можно использовать для создания шаблонов как в React ES6. `map(i=> <div>{this.phones[i]}</div>);`, т.е. вы получите новый массив, уже с элементами `<div /> ` между которыми будет текст с названием каждого телефона. Хотя можно сразу от `this.phones` взять `.map(el => el)`, где `el` будет имя телефона

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `map` одно предназначение вставить новое значение в поток. То есть если бы не было `map`, то на следующем шаге было бы значение равное `i`. А так будет возращенное значение, что в Вашем случаи элемент массива.

И я не видя всей конструкции могу сказать что именно в таком виде она кажется не совсем нормальной.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы, в просторах интернета я нашёл точный ответ на мой вопрос. Может кому пригодится, такая конструкция имеет название - "стрелочные функции", ну а дальше в инете много материала и примеров расписано на эту тему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/128522)

Comment: @Jean-Claude, в принципе, это ответ.